# Exclude same values and specific ruleset query

Tags: mysql, sql

it's been a while since I worked with databases and can't wrap my head around how to do these at the moment, so I would really appreciate it if anyone could lend me a hand with these two questions/queries.

1. I want to display the ID's that's been inside at least 2 DIFFERENT zones (exclude ID's that's ONLY been in the same zone).
2. I want to display the ID's that's first been in zone1, then zone2, then zone3 (need to look at time here).

Original:

> ```
> ID    ZONE    TIME 
> "01"  "ZO1"   "20190110_111326"
> "01"  "ZO1"   "20190110_111355" 
> "01"  "ZO1"   "20190110_111529"
> "02"  "ZO3"   "20190110_112527"
> "02"  "ZO3"   "20190110_112559"
> "06"  "ZO1"   "20190114_082144" 
> "06"  "ZO2"   "20190114_082153"
> "06"  "ZO3"   "20190114_082210" 
> "07"  "ZO3"   "20190114_131034"
> "07"  "ZO2"   "20190114_131058"
> ```

1.

```
ID      ZONE    TIME
"06"    "ZO1"   "20190114_082144"
"06"    "ZO2"   "20190114_082153"
"06"    "ZO3"   "20190114_082210"
"07"    "ZO3"   "20190114_131034"
"07"    "ZO2"   "20190114_131058"
```

2.

```
ID      ZONE    TIME
"06"    "ZO1"   "20190114_082144"
"06"    "ZO2"   "20190114_082153"
"06"    "ZO3"   "20190114_082210"
```

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT etc.

Comment: Your question is too broad (you have two questions).  The second is quite ambiguous -- what happens when multiple zones are interleaved?  I would suggest asking each question separately.

Comment: @jarlh has a spot on comment here. These keywords can be used widely. 
I would try reading up on those keywords, and see if you can ask a more specific and clear question. Note that the post above actually has no question at all. It would be easier to read with actual question sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER TO # 1

```
select * from table where id in 
(
select id from
(
   select id, zone
   from table 
   group by id, zone
)
group by id 
having count(1) > 1

)
```

ANSWER TO # 2

```
select t2.zone, t2.time, max(t2.id) as id from 
(select zone, min(time) minTime from table group by zone ) t1
join 
(select id, zone, time from table) t2 on t1.zone = t2.zone and t1.minTime = t2.time
group by t2.zone, t2.time
```

Note the reason why we got a max id on the second query is b/c there might be more than 1 at the same time.